# Lock a channel in discord but users are alowed to see the channel

Tags: discord

Let me start off by telling you what I am doing and what result I am getting. So I have a role defined as **members**, they are not allowed to view the contents of the **admin** channel.

So I go to channel settings> permissions>member role and uncheck the read messages option. Doing so makes the channel dissapear for the member.

What I want is the user should be able to see that there is channel but not able to click on it as shown in the image.

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not able to be done with text channels, but it is able to be done for voice channels.

By disallowing the `Connect` permission for the role of your choice (either at the `Category` permission level or the `Channel` permission level,) members of your server with the aforementioned role will be able to see the voice channel, but not be able to click it (or connect to it). Disallowing the `View Channel` permission will remove its visibility entirely.

**Beware**: Members with the `Move Members` permission will ignore the disallowed `Connect` permission. Members with this permission may also move other users into any channel they can see, regardless of whether that user or the user they're moving has the `Connect` permission for that voice channel or not.

Here's a screenshot of the permission you're looking for:

[image: Connect Permission]

Doing something similar for a text channel is not currently possible. Disallowing the `Read Message History` permission will still permit users to see messages in the related channel, however only while the channel is focused by them (the history is cleared each time the channel is no longer focused). Disallowing the `View Channel` permission simply hides the text channel entirely.